# How to access a string array?(Android)

Tags: java, android, xml, arrays, string

I'm a `beginner Android Developer`.
I would like to find out how I could access a `string array out of` **string.xml** and use it.
I searched the internet inside out and found nothing.
I found ways to put it into text-view right away, but that's not what I want to do. So, basically, I want to put the `string array into another array`.
**string.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>
<string-array name="Solar System">
    <item>Sun</item>
    <item>Mercury</item>
    <item>Venus</item>
    <item>Earth</item>
    <item>Mars</item>
    <item>Jupiter</item>
    <item>Saturn</item>
    <item>Uranus</item>
    <item>Neptune</item>
```

So I want this xml string array into a java string array

Thank's for the POSITIVE HELP,
I'm sorry, I thought that way that was shown by many of you didn't work. It was just another error in my program.

-Thanks

Comment: Both answer is right please check and accept if helpful.

Comment: `I searched the internet inside out and found nothing`.  Really?  What did you search for?  Unicorn food?  Here's a tutorial. http://bit.ly/1d4sEcJ

Comment: http://www.unicorns.co.za/unicorn-facts/unicorn-food.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below

```
String[] planets = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Planets);
```

Answer (score 1):

Seriously? The [example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray) where you got that from even shows how you to access it:

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] planets = res.getStringArray(R.array.Planets);
```

Comment: I didn't get it from that example, not even close

Comment: If you scroll down a bit to the example, it is exactly the same. All you did was change the name.